# Unable to log in to Apache FTP Server

Tags: apache, ftp

I am trying to integrate the Apache FTP server into my application. I have followed the instructions given [here](http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/embedding_ftpserver.html) but have run into some problems. Currently I am able to run the server and connect to it from my browser but can not log in. I have tried admin/admin and anonymous/*, but the login fails every time. In the apache-ftpserver-1.0.6 source code I had downloaded, the files associated with the user manager are located in res/conf, although when I try to match that file path in my own program I get an error that says "invalid resource directory name" and am unable to build. I also tried including the files users.properties and ftpd-typical.xml in the main directly and can run, but again cannot log in.  It seems like my project does not realize these files are present.

Does anyone have experience with Apache FTP Server that could tell me the correct way to include these files so that I can log in to my server?

Thanks!

P.S. I don't think it should make any difference, but I am developing this program for Android.

Comment: Dear there are lots of tutorials available

Answer (score 4):

In the following code I am crating admin user and non-admin user, setting restrictions of reading, writing and restricting throttling and upload rate limit and imposing download rate limiting.

Added a listener to listen user login and logout download start and download finish events.

```
 import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

    import org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServer;
    import org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerFactory;
    import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.Authority;
    import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FileSystemFactory;
    import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpException;
    import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.Ftplet;
    import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.UserManager;
    import org.apache.ftpserver.ftpletcontainer.impl.DefaultFtpletContainer;
    import org.apache.ftpserver.listener.ListenerFactory;
    import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.PropertiesUserManagerFactory;
    import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.SaltedPasswordEncryptor;
    import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.impl.BaseUser;
    import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.impl.ConcurrentLoginPermission;
    import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.impl.TransferRatePermission;
    import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.impl.WritePermission;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    public class SFTPServer {

        // ===========================================================
        // Constants
        // ===========================================================
        private final int FTP_PORT = 2221;
        private final String DEFAULT_LISTENER = "default";
        // private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SFTPServer.class);
        private static final List<Authority> ADMIN_AUTHORITIES;
        private static final int BYTES_PER_KB = 1024;
        private static final String DEFAULT_USER_DIR = "C:\\upload";

        public final static int MAX_CONCURRENT_LOGINS = 1;
        public final static int MAX_CONCURRENT_LOGINS_PER_IP = 1;

        // ===========================================================
        // Fields
        // ===========================================================
        private static FtpServer mFTPServer;
        private static UserManager mUserManager;
        private static FtpServerFactory mFTPServerFactory;
        private ListenerFactory mListenerFactor;

        // ===========================================================
        // Constructors
        // ===========================================================
        static {
            // Admin Authorities
            ADMIN_AUTHORITIES = new ArrayList<Authority>();
            ADMIN_AUTHORITIES.add(new WritePermission());
            ADMIN_AUTHORITIES.add(new ConcurrentLoginPermission(MAX_CONCURRENT_LOGINS, MAX_CONCURRENT_LOGINS_PER_IP));
            ADMIN_AUTHORITIES.add(new TransferRatePermission(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        }

        // ===========================================================
        // Getter & Setter
        // ===========================================================

        // ===========================================================
        // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
        // ===========================================================

        // ===========================================================
        // Methods
        // ===========================================================
        public void init() throws FtpException {
            mFTPServerFactory = new FtpServerFactory();
            mListenerFactor = new ListenerFactory();
            mListenerFactor.setPort(FTP_PORT);

            mFTPServerFactory.addListener(DEFAULT_LISTENER, mListenerFactor.createListener());
            mFTPServerFactory.getFtplets().put(FTPLetImpl.class.getName(), new FTPLetImpl());

            PropertiesUserManagerFactory userManagerFactory = new PropertiesUserManagerFactory();
            userManagerFactory.setFile(new File("ftpusers.properties"));
            userManagerFactory.setPasswordEncryptor(new SaltedPasswordEncryptor());
            mUserManager = userManagerFactory.createUserManager();
            mFTPServerFactory.setUserManager(mUserManager);

            this.createAdminUser();
            SFTPServer.addUser("admin1", "admin1", 20, 20);

            mFTPServer = mFTPServerFactory.createServer();

            mFTPServer.start();
        }

        private UserManager createAdminUser() throws FtpException {
            UserManager userManager = mFTPServerFactory.getUserManager();
            String adminName = userManager.getAdminName();

            if (!userManager.doesExist(adminName)) {
                // LOG.info((new
                // StringBuilder()).append("Creating user : ").append(adminName).toString());
                BaseUser adminUser = new BaseUser();
                adminUser.setName(adminName);
                adminUser.setPassword(adminName);
                adminUser.setEnabled(true);
                adminUser.setAuthorities(ADMIN_AUTHORITIES);
                adminUser.setHomeDirectory(DEFAULT_USER_DIR);
                adminUser.setMaxIdleTime(0);
                userManager.save(adminUser);
            }

            return userManager;
        }

        public static void addUser(String username, String password, int uploadRateKB, int downloadRateKB) throws FtpException {

            BaseUser user = new BaseUser();
            user.setName(username);
            user.setPassword(password);
            user.setHomeDirectory(DEFAULT_USER_DIR);
            user.setEnabled(true);

            List<Authority> list = new ArrayList<Authority>();
            list.add(new TransferRatePermission(downloadRateKB * BYTES_PER_KB, uploadRateKB * BYTES_PER_KB)); // 20KB
            list.add(new ConcurrentLoginPermission(MAX_CONCURRENT_LOGINS, MAX_CONCURRENT_LOGINS_PER_IP));

            user.setAuthorities(list);

            mFTPServerFactory.getUserManager().save(user);
        }

        public static void restartFTP() throws FtpException {
            if (mFTPServer != null) {
                mFTPServer.stop();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 * 3);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                mFTPServer.start();
            }
        }

        public static void stopFTP() throws FtpException {
            if (mFTPServer != null) {
                mFTPServer.stop();
            }
        }

        public static void pauseFTP() throws FtpException {
            if (mFTPServer != null) {
                mFTPServer.suspend();
            }
        }

        public static void resumeFTP() throws FtpException {
            if (mFTPServer != null) {
                mFTPServer.resume();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String... are) {
            try {
                new SFTPServer().init();
            } catch (FtpException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // ===========================================================
        // Inner and Anonymous Classes
        // ===========================================================

    }
```

> FTPLET Listener

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.DefaultFtplet;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpException;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpRequest;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpSession;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpletResult;

public class FTPLetImpl extends DefaultFtplet {

    @Override
    public FtpletResult onLogin(FtpSession session, FtpRequest request) throws FtpException, IOException {
        System.out.println(session.getUser().getName() + " Logged in");
        return super.onLogin(session, request);
    }

    @Override
    public FtpletResult onDisconnect(FtpSession session) throws FtpException, IOException {
        System.out.println(session.getUser().getName() + " Disconnected");
        return super.onDisconnect(session);
    }

    @Override
    public FtpletResult onDownloadStart(FtpSession session, FtpRequest request) throws FtpException, IOException {
        System.out.println(session.getUser().getName() + " Started Downloading File " + request.getArgument());
        return super.onDownloadStart(session, request);
    }

    @Override
    public FtpletResult onDownloadEnd(FtpSession session, FtpRequest request) throws FtpException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Finished Downloading " + request.getArgument());
        return super.onDownloadEnd(session, request);
    }

}
```

[image: Connecting to FTP]

Comment: This worked for me. I am able to connect and see the directory structure now, however I cannot write files.

Comment: Which OS you are using? You need to give write access on that folder

Comment: I was some how creating two users.  admin and admin2.  Admin2 was not getting the write permission.  Fixed it.  Thank you.